# How to listen for mspc messages and run an api server with actix rust?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am new to rust, just trying to figure out how to listen for mspc messages and run an API server with actix. Currently, the code stops in tokio::spawn which makes sense, not sure what is the right way to implement it.

My code:

```
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()>  {
    let (tx, mut rx): (Sender<Message>, Receiver<Message>) = channel(30);
    let db_client = utils::connection::init()
        .await
        .expect("Failed to connect to DB");

    let _ = tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(msg) = rx.recv().await {
            match msg.msg_type {
                Done => {
                    // Start again
                    println!("Start the task again")
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .await;


    println!("{}", "Server started! 8080");
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(db_client.postgres.clone()))
            .service(sample_api)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Comment: Don't `await` the result of the `spawn`.

Answer (score 1):

When you `.await` the result of `spawn()`, you wait for the spawned task to complete. But it runs infinitely, and by waiting for it you block the code that should send data to `rx` - so a deadblock.

Remove the `.await` from it.